# spring boot custom login page

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to add a custom login page for my boot strap application. I was following [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html) tutorial. I couldn't make work with my custom login page.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
...
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
...
```

MvcConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");

        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

}
```

FrontendApp.java:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

 @SpringBootApplication
 @Import(value = MvcConfig.class)
 public class FrontendApp {

      private static Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(FrontendApp.class);

      public static void main(String[] args) {

          SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(FrontendApp.class);
          app.run(args);
     }

}
```

SecurityConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
         auth.authenticationProvider(this.customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login");
    }

}
```

I opened all the url's so Ican just check whether I can see /login or not.
CustomAuthenticationProvider.java

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {    

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);


    public CustomAuthenticationProvider() {
        logger.info("*** CustomAuthenticationProvider created");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
         return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        if(authentication.getName().equals("karan")  && authentication.getCredentials().equals("saman")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuths);
         } else {
              return null;
         }
    }

}
```

When I try localhost:8080/login I will get the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "login", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

However when I try localhost:8080/ it will successfully redirect to index.html as I specified in MvcConfig.java.

Here is my login.html code:

```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
         xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
         xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
         xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>k</title> 
</head>
```

I paste my login.html in /src/main/resources/templates and /src/main/webapp/ and /src/main/webapp/templates it still didn't work!

Comment: You view controller config must be intercepting the 'login' request and redirecting to a non existent 'login' page, hence the error. This is bypassing the thymeleaf view resolver. Have you tried removing the line: `registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");` from your MvcConfig?

Comment: @FinbarrO'Brien Yes, tried. In fact I tried adding something else like login1 and put the corresponding login1.html in templates but I got the same error for that one as well.

Comment: Are you building your application as a war file or executable jar?

Comment: @FinbarrO'Brien I'm Using Embedded Tomcat and building it as a executable jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so it was a simple mistake in pom.xml.

```
<!--<resources>-->
        <!--<resource>-->
            <!--<directory>src/main/resources</directory>-->
            <!--<includes>-->
                <!--<include>*</include>-->
            <!--</includes>-->
            <!--<filtering>true</filtering>-->
        <!--</resource>-->
    <!--</resources>-->
```

After I commented out these (as you see) from the pom file it worked perfectly.At least the above codes might be useful to someone else.